# Add checkbox from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML page that contains only an empty `<div id="data"></div>` and in javascript, I got the information from the database through the ajax and return it back to javascript then print it out in the `<div id="data"></div>`

I've set the data to be in the columns, now if I want to add another column and this column would contain a button if I click on it then the row will be deleted. (I know how to do the delete through ajax and return it back, etc..) but **the question is how could I do the button?**

If I add it inside the `div = data` it will be printed once, and if I add it inside the javascript file then I won't able to add a click listener .. how could I do that?

```js
        let printItems = document.getElementById("data");
  function succes(user) {
        let info = "<div class='infoTable'>";
        for (let i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
            info += "<div class='info'>";
            info += "<div class='fcol'>" + (i+1) + "</div>";
            info += "<div class='scol'>" + user[i].name + "</div>"; 
            info += "<div class='tcol'>" + user[i].quantity + "</div>";
            info += "I NEED TO ADD THE BUTTON HERE TO HAVE user[i].ID";
            info += "</div>";
        }
        info += "</div>";
        printinfo.innerHTML = info;
    }
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you did the hard part. What you are looking is very easy and you can do that in more than one way. I can suggest you an easier way to me. Write a function which delete the row (from UI and ajax). Now your problem is how to call that function for each row. So you can attach a `onclick` function for every row you created.
For example:

```
info += '<button onclick="deleteRowFunction"> Delete This<button />';
```

Now every time you click the button your delete function called. But how to determine which function is called?
That can be solved by following ways:

```
info += '<button onclick="deleteRowFunction(\'' + user[i].ID + '\')"> Delete This<button />';
```

The other easy way is to use `data-` attribute:

For example:

```
info += '<button data-userId=' + user[i].ID + ' onclick="deleteRowFunction"> Delete This<button />';
```

In this way you can get the `ID` in the `deleteRowFunction`. You can read all the details [here](https://www.thewebdeveloperguide.com/javascript-get-data-attribute/)

Comment: Thanks @Rafik Farhad, I have a question, why you wrote the function lilk this onclick="deleteRowFunction(\'' + user[i].ID + '\')"> instead of this onclick='deleteRowFunction(" + item[i].id + ")'> since the id is int not string

Comment: Bro, also when I tried it and click on it it shows this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: deletee is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)
onclick @ (index):1

Comment: Its trying to find in HTML page

Answer (score 0):

```js
const user = [{
  name: "ABC",
  quantity: 2,
}, {
  name: "XYZ",
  quantity: 1,
}, {
  name: "abcdef",
  quantity: 12,
}];
let printItems = document.getElementById("data");

function deleteButton(e){
  const targetButton = e.target;
  targetButton.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}

function succes(user) {
  let info = "<div class='infoTable'>";
  
  for (let i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
    info += `<div class='info'>
               <div class='fcol'>${(i + 1)}</div>
               <div class='scol'>${user[i].name}</div>
               <div class='tcol'>${user[i].quantity}</div>
               <div class='tcol'><button onclick="deleteButton(event)">Delete</div>
             </div>`;
  }
  
  info += "</div>";
  printItems.innerHTML = info;
}

succes(user);
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```